# How to spilt or RegExp the string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a error string like this

```
/code/test.java:3: error: unclosed string literal\n       
System.out.println(\"Hello World!)      \n                           
^\n/code/test.java:3: error: ';' expected\n        
System.out.println(\"Hello World!)      \n   
^\n/code/test.java:5: error: reached end of file while parsing\n}\n ^\n3 errors\n
```

and i want to parse this string to get two arrays

The first array is
`[error: unclosed string literal System.out.println("Hello World!) , error: ';' expected System.out.println("Hello World!) , error: reached end of file while parsing }]`
and the second array is `[3,3,5]`

in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wsqo0wo/7/),I already get the first array that I wanted but how to get the second array?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the second array:

```
var error_string="/code/test.java:3: error: unclosed string literal\n        System.out.println(\"Hello World!)      \n                           ^\n/code/test.java:3: error: ';' expected\n        System.out.println(\"Hello World!)      \n                                               ^\n/code/test.java:5: error: reached end of file while parsing\n}\n ^\n3 errors\n";
var second_array = [];
do
{
    match = re.exec(str2);
    if(match)
        second_array.push(match[1]);
}while(match);
document.getElementById("str2").innerHTML = second_array.toString();
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jr7qLz63/)